# Can a server post a broadcast message to terminate workers? Rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue

For instance, if a worker is processing a message from the queue, is there a way to broadcast a message to all the workers to stop processing their work?

I'm using **rabbitmq queue**.

I need to pause the workers.

let's say four parallel payment workers are running.
Like, many customers doing the payment on Amazon, each request from the customer pushed into the queue, the worker will take request message from the queue

```
def payment_worker():
      check_account_is_valid()
      check_card_id_valid()
      post_to_paymentGateway() #it has only one merchant (lets' say AMAZON PAY)
```

so if four payment workers are running parallel, if one of the workers failed on post_to_paymentGateway  method, I need to pause remaining workers till the Amazon pay resolved. So that when I resume a worker there won't be any further payment failure.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Why do you want to pause the workers? How do the other workers depend on the + worker?

Comment: Close the connection worker consumers belong? you can do this by [rabbitmq managment API](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api)

Comment: @menya I need to pause the workers, not close. Bcoz the paused workers need to start, where I have paused.

Comment: I think there is no way to do that. A consumer can only paused by itself called `channel.basicCancel(tag)`. If you want to keep channel open while `pause/resume` consumer, maybe add another queue contains `pause/resume` signal message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, it cant.**

If your workers are single-threaded and read from a shared work queue, then there is no way you can reliably "pause" them.  A possible approach would be for these workers to query some centralized mechanism (api, db, redis, etc.) for a "go" status before processing each message.